# Can't Read Twitter Json

Tags: json, twitter

I'm a total loss. I have this function to read the Twitter Json. The Json is valid but the value is coming back as 'undefined' when I run it.

```
$.getJSON("http://twitter.com/users/show.json?screen_name=starbucks&callback=?" , function(data) {
var testing = (data.length);
alert(testing);
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`data` is an object* not an array** so it doesn't have a length property.***

Use a debugger like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com), [Safari](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/safari/developer-tools.html)/[Chrome](http://www.chromium.org/devtools) dev tools and use this code instead:

```
$.getJSON("http://twitter.com/users/show.json?screen_name=starbucks&callback=?" ,
    function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

and you can see that the data is coming back to you perfectly.

[Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/4vXP2/2/) to see what I mean, preferably with a JavaScript console available.

---

*e.g., something that looks like `{key: value, ...}`; also known as a hash or an associative array

**e.g., something that looks like: `[foo, bar, baz, ...]`

*** unless, of course, someone was evil and constructed the object like so:

```
data = {
    ...
    length: 8675309,
    ...
};
```

Comment: Aha, ok. And thanks for letting me know about the console. This is a fantastic feature. Iv'e been dealing with alert boxes this whole time.

Comment: @egfx: wow, that's horrible! My life would be miserable without a proper JavaScript debugger.

Comment: Welcome to this is your (developer) life 2018, haha. Memories. Whoever, thanks for the downvote on the main question, I would have completely forgotten about this!